# How to connect wired clients of TWO routers that are connected through WDS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wds

So I have two routers running:

**Router 1**: ADSL Modem router (some Huawei model provided by my phone company)  to which my phone line is connected. Machine A is connected to this router through wire. This router's IP is **192.168.1.1** and is running DHCP.

**Router 2**: TP-Link router (MR3420) to which Machine B is connected through wire. This router's IP is **192.168.1.2**. This router is **NOT** running DHCP. Machine B therefore has been assigned static IP **192.168.1.15**. Turning on DHCP results in the router no longer being accessible from Machine B.

The two routers are connected through WDS, which is running fine. A few things about the current setup:

1. I can see WDS Status = Run in admin dashboard of router 2.
2. I can ping Router 2 from Machine A.
3. I cannot ping Router 1 from Machine B.
4. I cannot ping either machine from the other machine.
5. I cannot access the Internet from Machine B.

I have spent the whole day today just trying to figure out what's wrong with the setup. Can anyone help?

### UPDATE

Partial success! I ended up flashing Router 2 with [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) and can finally access the Internet (provided by Wifi of Router 1) on Machine B now!

But I still can't ping Machine A or Router 1 from Machine B. I have installed the **relayd** package too and bridged the LAN and WAN connections, to create a **bridged repeater connection**, which if I understand it correctly, would theoretically allow all the machines connected to either Router 1 or Router 2 to access each other as if they were connected to a single router; plus also allowing machines connected to Router 2 to access the Internet.

Hope someone can help me to resolve this last remaining problem.

Comment: Don't use the WAN port on router 2, plug router 1 into a LAN port of router 2.  If the network is correct, you don't need to give Machine B a static IP, DHCP of router 1 should serve to the entire network.

Comment: @Tyson: The two routers can't be connected through wire (environment restrictions). They're wirelessly connected using WDS. Router 2 is essentially acting as a repeater.

Comment: I confess I should have looked up the meaning of WDS, and I'll shut up now since I've never used a tp-link product

Comment: Is the default gateway set in Machine B? It should be the IP of router 2

Comment: @GaneshR.: Yes. I have even tried to set it to the IP of router 1 or keeping it empty. All three configurations do not work.

Comment: See http://www.tp-link.us/faq-227.html

Comment: @GaneshR.: No luck. I've almost given up. Looks like a wired connection between the two routers is the only way. I'll see how to cope with the physical restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not capable with those products.  You either need a wired connection between router 1 and 2 or you need to use a range extender instead of router 2 as that product (the TP-Link router) is incapable of doing that function.